# How have Guava unit tests been generated automatically?

Tags: automated-testing

[Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) library for Java has unit test cases [automatically generated](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/PhilosophyExplained):

> Guava has staggering numbers of unit tests: as of July 2012, the
>   guava-tests package includes over 286,000 individual test cases. Most
>   of these are **automatically** generated, not written by hand, but Guava's
>   test coverage is extremely thorough, especially for
>   com.google.common.collect.

How they were generated? What techniques and technologies were used to design and generate them?

**My guess**

My first guess is they follow *parametrized tests* approach. The package [com.google.common.collect.testing](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/source/browse/guava-testlib/src/com/google/common/collect/testing/) has a lot of classes with "Generator" in their names -- making it look like a framework for tests generation. The package [com.google.common.collect.testing.features](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/source/browse/guava-testlib/src/com/google/common/collect/testing/#testing/features) lists the features/constrains that a "collection" implementation (e.g., for a list, a set) should satisfy. So a test case parametrize what features a particular implementation should have.

**Motivation**

My [original question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/173167/how-have-guava-unit-tests-been-generated-automatically) on Programmers SE got much attention from the community but no reasonable answer, so I'm trying to get it here. My motivation behind such a question is to learn more *in general* about techniques (parametrized tests, random tests, etc.) and technologies (code templates, etc.) used to automate test case generation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Also answered at the original question on [programmers.stackexchange.com](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/173167))

A large part of this mass of tests is for their collection implementations. They've written generic tests that exhaustively test the collection interfaces, and this generates a suite per implementation. See, for example, classes called `CollectionAddAllTester`, `ListIndexOfTester`.

This is all backed by a library called testlib, which ships as part of Guava. This is quite generic. It supports writing generic tests for any interface (not just collections). You can specify `Feature`s of possible implementations and test those (e.g. if your set is unmodifiable you expect a different outcome from `set.add()`), and when you run the tests you specify which features your implementation supports.

I [wrote a post](http://www.joekearney.co.uk/posts/guava-testlib-example) on how to write testlib generating suites for your own interfaces.

Answer (score 1):

One possibility is the use of CodePro Analytix by Google which has a [JUnit Test Case Generation](https://developers.google.com/java-dev-tools/codepro/doc/features/junit/test_case_generation) feature.

Comment: Can you explain more how it works?

Comment: Its probably similar to how SoapUI can read a webservice WSDL and then it knows how to generate all the stubs for all the endpoint methods.  I would guess CodePro Analytix must use Reflection to generate tests (or at least the stubs)?  This is a total guess: stab in the dark.

Comment: So it just generate stubs, correct?